# Replace not replacing lines

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script to find and replace lines in my bspwmrc config. When I run this code it finds the string but fails to replace it.

Here's my code:

```
import os 

 def main():
     bspwmrc_path = '/home/arch/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc'

     with open(bspwmrc_path, 'r+') as bspwmrc:
         for line in bspwmrc:
             if "bspc config border_width           4" in line:
                 line.replace('bspc config border_width           4', 'bspc config border_width               0')
             elif "bspc config border_width           0" in line:
                 line.replace('bspc config border_width           0', 'bspc config border_width               4')
     bspwmrc.write()
     bspwmrc.close()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
     # os.system('/home/$USER/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc')
```

Comment: Okay, and what is your *question*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As stated I'm getting `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable` I'm looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to swap out lines in a file without having to create a second file using `sed`. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

```
import os


def main():
    bspwmrc_path = '/home/arch/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc'
    output_path = '/home/arch/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc_output'

    with open(bspwmrc_path) as bspwmrc:
        for line in bspwmrc:
            if 'bspc config border_width           4' in line:
                os.system("sed -i 's/bspc config border_width           4/bspc config border_width           0/g' /home/arch/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc")


            elif 'bspc config border_width           0' in line:
                os.system("sed -i 's/bspc config border_width           0/bspc config border_width           4/g' /home/arch/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    os.system('/home/$USER/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc')
```